# How its made such as digicoder vcr dvd players graphical user interfaces from poweron till user interface?

Tags: c, embedded, linux-kernel, hardware, kernel

I have C/Java knowledge but i never understand yet, how some hardwares show there own screens/graphics from poweron stage to user interface (where it never shows linux/unix boot screen nor it shows windows booting screens).

My question is, Compared to VCR/TV digicoders poweron till user interfaces, how its made? Do we use regular linux kernel or is there any special open source framework which allow us to develop such?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A device will start the bootloader right after the CPU comes out of reset (usually milliseconds after power-on at most).  The bootloader code can initialize the display and show a splash screen if it wants (in the same way most modern non-embedded Linux distributions have a graphical grub splashscreen).  The kernel can avoid changing the display configuration, and on an embedded device the kernel can boot pretty quickly to running userspace (at least an initramfs), which can take over the display and show whatever animation, progress bar, etc until the full UI is ready.

Comment: That means for embedded PC we use U-Boot, and for general PC / server platform we can use Grub? But how does Grub splash screen gets changed, is this the same way like U-Boot?

Comment: Search the web for something like "grub splash customize" and you will find many answers for the specifics.

Comment: The question was "Compared to VCR/TV digicoders...", I doubt many of these are even that complex.  Not all embedded systems have and OS or even a boot-loader.  This answer is not generalised.

Comment: VCRs probably don't run an OS, but many HDTVs in fact run Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Many embedded systems use [u-boot](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/) as a boot loader. U-boot provides the ability to display a ["splash" screen](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootSplashScreen) while the linux kernel is booting.

Comment: This is a great information in my carrier to learn and study further. I am desperate to do such, i really looking for such related informations more and more.

Answer (score 0):

An operating systems such a Windows or Linux are both large and general purpose.  They have to initialise themselves and the hardware, which includes interrogating all connected devices for "plug & play".  The OS does not know in advance which such devices are connected; it has to "discover" the hardware every time it starts.  The connected hardware may even have changed since it last booted.

Embedded systems do not usually have large operating systems (or often do not have an operating system at all), and they usually have very specific hardware known to the system *a priori*, so do not need to test and determine the correct configuration for such devices.  Often also these devices are far simpler, and are often 'on-chip' peripherals.

That said, your PC is capable of instantly displaying a user interface (just not Windows).  The BIOS boot process outputs text to the display almost immediately, and the BIOS console is an interactive user interface that starts on request during boot.  Also last time I booted MS-DOS on a modern PC, it took only a few seconds to start.

Not all embedded systems start "instant-on", my digital TV PVR even has a progress bar while booting, but being application specific, it still starts far faster than a general purpose computer.  My Network Attached Storage (NAS) device which is an embedded system running Linux on the other hand, takes considerable time to boot since among other things, it has to start the file-system, network, USB interfaces, print server, DNLA server, and web-server. In fact many of the things required for a general purpose computer (but it has no display, the UI is presented via the web-server)

Some embedded systems with large operating systems and complex hardware can achieve "instant-on" by never truly switching off, but rather going into a low power mode where the *system state* is retained in memory while all the high powered devices such as a screen, WiFi, Bluetooth etc. are switched off.